# When does heat kernel exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, heat-equation

I have a question about heat kernel.

> **Definition**
>
> Let $(X,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $L$ be a densely
>   defined closed linear operator on real Hilber space $L^{2}(X)$ such
>   that
>
> 1. $(Lu,u)_{L^{2}}\leq 0$ for all $u \in D(L)$
> 2. $(\alpha -L)(D(L))=L^{2}(X)$ for some $\alpha>0$
>
> Then there exists strongly continuous contraction semigroup (denoted by $e^{tL})$
>   on $L^{2}(X)$ corresponding to $L$ (Hille-Yosida's theorem) 
>   If $e^{tL}$ is given by a kernel $p(t,x,y)$, that is, a measurable
>   function on $X \times X$ such that
>
> $e^{tL}f(x)=\int_{X}p(t,x,y)f(y)\,\mu(dy)$ a.e. $x \in X$ for all $t>0$, $f
>  \in L^{2}(X)$
>
> and such that $|p(t,x,y)| \leq Ct^{-d/2}$ for all $t>0$, where $C,d$ are positive constants (independent of $t,x,y$). 
>   **We call the kernel $p(t,x,y)$ the heat kernel of $L$.**

**My question**

1. Are there any sufficient conditions for the existence of heat kernel?
2. When $X$ is a infinite dimensional space, is it difficult for heat kernel to exist?

If you know, please tell me. Thank you in advance?

Comment: What is $d$ in your heat kernel estimate?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.

Comment: Does the constant $d$ depend on $x,y$ (usually one would expect a dependence one some kind of distance between $x$ and $y$)? And do you want this estimate to hold for all $t>0$ or just short time/long time behavior?

Comment: Sorry, I improved this post. Thank you for pointing it out.